Unable to upload to the specific folder
I was trying to move a uploaded file to the folder on the root directly in xamp but I get the following error:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/opt/lampp/temp/phpXmFqCl" to "receiptupload/6610415dbe89e2.84901183.RecXPX08039484186.png" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/altech-classroom-master/payment_details.php on line 45

